# selenium python function not running

Tags: python, class, selenium

I have the following script which uses selenium, but it's not working. It just prints out "ok3" which shows it only made it to the first part of the class.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    print('ok3')
    binary = FirefoxBinary("/Users/djnewt/Desktop/Python/geckodriver")
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
    self.driver.get("http://google.com")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_selenium_1(self):
        print('ok4')
        search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
        search_field.send_keys("Test 1. Number 1")
        search_field.submit()
        print("ok1")
        time.sleep(2)


x = Test()
x.test_selenium_1()
x.tearDown()
```

I can't figure out what might be going wrong. The firefox browser window doesnt launch either and the function doesnt stop when the tearDown function is called.

Comment: indentation is wrong, put class methods actually into class

Comment: Yes, this is formatting problemw with SO, will see if I can add some indents - but still the original problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update selenium(3.3.0) ,firefox(52) and geckodriver(0.15)

add driver to path and initialize Firefox() directly

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
 def __init__(self):
      print('ok3')
      binary = FirefoxBinary("D:\\1.Manoj\\2.Soft-war\\5.Rest\\geckodriver.exe")
      self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()#firefox_binary=binary)
      self.driver.get("http://google.com")

 def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

 def test_selenium_1(self):
    print('ok4')
    search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    search_field.send_keys("Test 1. Number 1")
    search_field.submit()
    print("ok1")
    time.sleep(2)


x = Test()
x.test_selenium_1()
x.tearDown()
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use  selenium 2.35.1 with firefox 46.0.1, because the latest  version of selenium isn't compatible with  Firefox browser

Comment: This  should be a comment, not an answer.